# Community : undesirable blank DOM element

Tags: community, community-builder

I am working on a SF Community and have this weird DOM blank element that seems to be generated by Salesforce. It appears on several pages, and I would like to **get rid of it**. Does anybody know how ? Thank you !

[image: Community screenshot]

Comment: hwo is this affecting your development? what are you trying to achieve and how is this DOM element impeding your development efforts?

Comment: The client can't stand it and I agree : this blank element makes the page scroll way too far, and I don't even understand where it could come from